# When the speed of CAReplicatorLayer is equal to 0, the copying effect disappears

Tags: objective-c

```
CAReplicatorLayer *replicatorLayer = [CAReplicatorLayer layer];
replicatorLayer.speed = 0.0;
replicatorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, self.size, self.size);

CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(circleSize + circlePadding, 0, 0);
replicatorLayer.instanceTransform = transform;
replicatorLayer.instanceCount = count;
replicatorLayer.instanceDelay = animationDuration / (count*2);

CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.size*0.5 - circleSize*0.5, circleSize, circleSize);
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
layer.cornerRadius = circleSize / 2;
layer.masksToBounds = YES;
layer.backgroundColor = self.tintColor.CGColor;
[replicatorLayer addSublayer:layer];
```

when set speed=0.0,sublayer is not copied.I want to pause the animation at sublayer of CAReplicatorLayer.

Comment: Maybe try giving it a very minimal speed (eg. `0.0001`).

Comment: Is there any better way?

Comment: Setting the speed to `0` will definitely stop it from replicating, so if you want to pause it after it replicates then maybe use an animation `repeatcount` and set it to 0.

Comment: Thanks,I found a solution. Set timeoffset of layer is useful